# removing rows from one dataframe based on condition on date condition on the other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have following dataframes
df1

```
id        date_col      No. of leaves
100       2018-10-05      4
100       2018-10-14      4
100       2018-10-19      4
100       2018-11-15      4
101       2018-10-05      3
101       2018-10-08      3
101       2018-12-05      3
```

df2

```
id        date_col       leaves_availed
100       2018-11-28       2
100       2018-11-29       2
101       2018-11-19       2
101       2018-11-24       2
```

I want rows for the particular id and date in df1 that are smaller than date in df2 for the particular id and then remove the row with the earliest date,and 
subtract the number of leaves_availed from "No. of leaves.

in the above example the resultant dataframe should be

```
id        date_col      No. of leaves
100       2018-10-19      2
100       2018-11-15      2
101       2018-12-05      1
```

for id=100 and date 2018-11-28 in df2,the rows that have date less than 2018-11-28 are

```
id        date_col      No. of leaves
100       2018-10-05      4
100       2018-10-14      4
100       2018-10-19      4
100       2018-11-15      4
```

and the the earliest date in this subset is   2018-10-05 
thus, row  `100       2018-10-05      4` will be removed and so on

Right now,i have sorted both dataframes

```
df1.sort_values(by=['id','date_col'],inplace=True)
df2.sort_values(by=['id','date_col'],inplace=True)
```

and iam trying remove top rows in df1 based on number of rows in df2,but it's leading me nowhere

Comment: For `'id'=100` you have 4 rows in `df1` and 2 rows  in `df2`. But you are only removing the earliest from `df1`. Then how do you subtract?

Comment: you have to do this logic for each row of df2?

Answer (score 0):

Following your logic, but without test all exceptions

```
import pandas as pd

def process(row):
    return row['No. of leaves'] - df2.iloc[0]['leaves_availed']

#recreate the different dataframe"
id1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [100, 100, 100, 100, 101, 101, 101]})
il1 = pd.DataFrame({'No. of leaves': [4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3]})
id2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [100, 100, 101, 101]})
il2 = pd.DataFrame({'leaves_availed': [2, 2, 2, 2]})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018],
                   'month': [10,   10,   10,   11,   10,   10,   12],
                     'day': [5,    14,   19,   15,    5,   8,    5]})    
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2018, 2018, 2018, 2018],
                   'month': [11,   11,   11,   11],
                     'day': [28,   29,   19,   24]})   
df1 = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(df1, format='%Y-%m-%d')).to_frame()
df1.columns = ["date_col"]
df1 = pd.concat([id1, df1, il1], axis=1)
df2 = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(df2, format='%Y-%m-%d')).to_frame()
df2.columns = ["date_col"]
df2 = pd.concat([id2, df2, il2], axis=1)    
df1.sort_values(by=['id','date_col'],inplace=True)
df2.sort_values(by=['id','date_col'],inplace=True)
#end of creation dafaframes

#loop each row of df2
for i in range(0, len(df2)):
    #filtering the df
    df3 = df1[(df1["date_col"] < df2.iloc[i]["date_col"]) & (df1['id'] == df2.iloc[i]['id']) ] 
    df3 = df3.iloc[1:]  #delete the oldest
    df3['No. of leaves'] = df3.apply(lambda row: process(row), axis = 1) #calculus the new leaves
    print(F"result for date {df2.iloc[i]['date_col']} and id =  {df2.iloc[i]['id']}")
    print(df3);print('-----------------\n')
```

the final result displayed

```
result for date 2018-11-28 00:00:00 and id =  100
    id   date_col  No. of leaves
1  100 2018-10-14              2
2  100 2018-10-19              2
3  100 2018-11-15              2
-----------------
result for date 2018-11-29 00:00:00 and id =  100
    id   date_col  No. of leaves
1  100 2018-10-14              2
2  100 2018-10-19              2
3  100 2018-11-15              2
-----------------
result for date 2018-11-19 00:00:00 and id =  101
    id   date_col  No. of leaves
5  101 2018-10-08              1
-----------------
result for date 2018-11-24 00:00:00 and id =  101
    id   date_col  No. of leaves
5  101 2018-10-08              1
-----------------
```